# Django Aggregate Sums over foreign key

Tags: python, sql, django, sum, aggregate-functions

I have the following models:

```
class Journey(models.Model):
      time = models.TimeField()
      distance = models.FloatField()

class Trip(models.Model):
      outward_journey = models.ForeignKey(Journey)
      return_journey = models.ForeignKey(Journey, null=True)
```

Now if I have a list of trips, I'd like to know the total distance travelled for all trips.

E.g. what I want is to Sum the `outward_journey` distances AND the `inward_journey` distances.
Is something like this possible with Django (with or without the `.extra()` statement. I've tried things like:

```
 Trip.objects.all().aggregate(out=Sum('outward_journey__distance'), in=Sum('return_journey_distance'))`
```

This one gives me a dict, (for which I could sum the values in Python) but that's not ideal, since the `return_journey` may be null (for one way trips), and hence the return_journey_distance may be `None`. i.e. I might get a dict like `{'outward_journey_distance' : 500, 'return_journey_distance' : None}`

I've also tried:

```
Trip.objects.all().extra(select={'distance' : 'SUM(outward_journey.distance) + SUM(inward_journey.distance)'})
```

but for this I get `ProgrammingError: missing FROM-clause entry for table "outward_journey"`

What's the cleanest way to get something like this done using the Django ORM? (as opposed to purely raw SQL)?

Edit:

My other idea was to get just the distances in Python, then to sum them using something like this, but as you can see it's not ideal/clear:

```
 distances = Trip.objects.all().values_list('outward_journey__distance', 'inward_journey__distance')
 # gives distances = ((11, 1), (20, None), (2, 2) ...)
 total_distance = sum([sum([d for d in each_distance if d]) for each_distance in distances)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine 2 querysets for this; one for one-way trips and one for return trips, like so:

```
round_trips = Trip.objects.exclude(return_journey__distance__isnull=True).aggregate(outward=Sum('outward_journey__distance'), inward=Sum('return_journey_distance'))
oneway_trips = Trip.objects.filter(return_journey__distance__isnull=True).aggregate(oneway=Sum('outward_journey__distance'))
```

To combine the two:

```
all_distances = dict(round_trips.items() + oneway_trips.items())
```

Or to get the total distance:

```
total_distance = round_trips.values() + oneway_trips.values()
```

Comment: That's another option, but it would be 2 SQL queries, not ideal. It's pretty clear though, so that's a plus :)